# How to split a linear String expression on the basis of operators

Tags: java, regex

I have a linear expression which I have to use for some calculation purpose. But I can not manage to use it properly by separating on the basis of operators. i.e I have an expression

```
"c*(a+b)+(a-b)"
```

from which I have to extract c,(a+b),(a-b) .I am able to separate c from there but I can not separate (a+b) and (a-b) .I am doing this

```
                String linearExp="c*(a+b)+(a-b)";
    String leftOperators=null;
    String rightOperators=null;

    for(int i=0;i<linearExp.length();i++){

        leftOperators=linearExp.substring(0,linearExp.lastIndexOf("*"));
        rightOperators=linearExp.substring(linearExp.lastIndexOf("*")+1);
    }
    System.out.println(leftOperators);
    System.out.println(rightOperators);
```

This is doing output like c &
(a+b)+(a-b).But I a need (a+b) &(a-b) separate also.somebody please help

Comment: provide some more inputs to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but it would seem to me that you would need some sort of stack or stacks to push variables and operators in on and to allow nesting of parenthesis if it occurs.

Comment: @subho there is a simple solution also for that.you can use the built-in Javascript engine .take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: The above code separate left side and right side of star character.. You need to separate based on the parenthesis... Use stack and start adding characters then if your encounter ( then pop everything from stack when u encounter ) pop till you get (... Try this..

Comment: can anyone provide regex to extract the operators also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solely based off your given expression and will not work for nested parenthesis.

One way using regex implementing lookarounds to split on the operators.

```
String s = "c*(a+b)+(a-b)";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\))[*+/-]|[*+/-](?=\\()");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); //=> [c, (a+b), (a-b)]
```

Comment: And when there are nested parenthesis -- what then? And when there are several levels of nesting? I'm sorry, but this is not the type of statement that should be solved with regular expressions.

Comment: I agree 100%, this is just based off his input expression.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you r write my actual problem goes with your idea

Comment: And i also need the operators also .can u suggest some help??